# jQuery - :not selector that works in css is not working with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to think that I'm good at identifying why things aren't working... but I am at a loss.

I added this style to my page to test and make sure I'm getting what I want...

```
*:not(.myclass):not(.myclass *)
{
    background-color: orange !important;
}
```

For some reason, these selectors

```
//I've tried this
$("*:not(.myclass):not(.myclass *)");
//and this
$(":not(.myclass):not(.myclass *)");
//and this
$(":not(.myclass)");
//and this
$("*:not(.myclass)");
```

select everything, instead of everything minus items with the class `myclass` and some of its children.

So when I run a custom method on the jQuery objects, it ends up doing it to all of the items instead of the ones with `myclass`.

Can anyone tell me why, or point me in the right direction. I've looked at several other posts that are related, but they haven't shed enough light on it for me.

Comment: It seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0uvo9af7/6/

Comment: Yes... it works with your fiddle... I made a few changes on my page to reflect the same idea... the only thing I can figure is that my custom method is screwing things up.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Yah... I will... I have to run... but when I come back I will... I just ran another test... it may not be what I thought

Comment: @Barmar replace .addClass('green') with .hide(); and you will see the problem. I have to leave... will be back in about 2hrs

Comment: As was suggested, your selector scope is too wide. It's generally a bad practice to select all. Try `$("body > *:not(.myclass):not(.myclass *)").addClass("green");` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the selector matches `html` and `body`, since they don't have the `myclass` class. So if you hide it, you're hiding everything. Use

```
$("*:not(.myclass,body,html):not(.myclass *)")
```

Comment: Ow! That hurts. Thank you!